# How to reuse states in redux-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am working on Redux-ToolKit to build an app that fetches the data from an API using. In my Redux store I have multiple slices and I would like to access the search state of the searchSlice inside the bookingSlice.Is there any way to solve this issue? I haven't been able to find a solution yet.

I am looking for best practice

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  destination: "",
  checkIn: new Date(),
  checkOut: new Date(),
  count: {
    adults: 2,
    children: 0,
    rooms: 1,
  },
  price: {
    min: 0,
    max: 500000,
  },
};

const searchSlice = createSlice({
  name: "search",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setDateRange: (state, { payload }) => {
      const { startDate, endDate } = payload;
      state.checkIn = startDate;
      state.checkOut = endDate;
    },
    increment: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.count[payload] += 1;
}
}

export default searchSlice.reducer;
```

Booking slice

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

const initialState = {
  search: ?
  bookings: [],
  isLoading: false,
  isSuccess: false,
  isError: false,
  message: "",
};

export const createBooking = createAsyncThunk(
  "booking/create",
  async (state, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post("api/bookings", { state });
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response && error.response.data.message) {
        return rejectWithValue(error.response.data.message);
      } else {
        return rejectWithValue(error.message);
      }
    }
  }
);

const bookingSlice = createSlice({
  name: "booking",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the state of another reducer inside a reducer. But you can use [getState()](https://redux.js.org/api/store#getstate) inside the `createBooking` action to get the current state tree of your application. Then filter what information you need from the `searchSlice` and return it from the action along with the api response.